# How to redefine kde4 keyboard shortcuts

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently switched to using KDE 4, and I don't like that KDE uses so many of the Ctrl-Fn shortcut keys, since I use them for other purposes. Specifically, I'd like to disable the Ctrl-F4 shortcut in KDE. However, I have not been able to find this shortcut in System Settings -> Shortcuts and Gestures.

UPDATE: Another shortcut I'd like to redefine is the "Show window menu" shortcut, which I like on Alt-Space, but which KDE has on Alt-F3.

I have not been able to find a global place to change all shortcuts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the global keyboard shortcuts are in "Settings -> System Settings -> Shortcuts and Gestures -> Global Keyboard Shortcuts".  You'll probably need to go through each of the KDE components to find and remove the shortcuts you don't want.

Comment: Very nice! I somehow managed to overlook the KDE Component dropdown list.

Answer (score 3):

I just found the solution to the Ctrl-F4 problem: The Ctrl-F4 shortcut switches to a different virtual desktop, so I have to right-click on the pager in the taskbar, select Pager Settings -> Virtual Desktops -> Switching. There I can define the shortcuts...

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the shortcuts via this menu path:

```
Configure Desktop
> Global Keyboard Shortcuts
 > KDE component
  > KWin
   > Window Operations Menu
```